# React component testing with mock data using Jest and Enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have the below component and need to write a test case using **Jest** and **Enzyme**

**Profile.js:**

```
//rest of the code

authenticationService.currentUser.subscribe(user => currentUser = user);
    return (
            <Card className="authentication">
                <img src="https://www.shareicon.net/data/128x128/2016/07/26/802043_man_512x512.png" class="rounded mx-auto d-block img-circle" alt="..." />
                <br />
                <h4>{currentUser._doc.name}</h4>
                <h6>{currentUser._doc.role}</h6>
                <hr />
                <p>Contact Details</p>
                <p>E-mail: <a href={"mailto:"+ currentUser._doc.email}>{currentUser._doc.email}</a></p>
            </Card>
    );
```

I tried the below test case, but it fails and got this error because I have used dynamic data in my JSX. `TypeError: Cannot read property '_doc' of null`

```
it("renders without crashing", () => {
    shallow(<Profile />);
});
```

In order to overcome this, I have created a dummy `currentUser` object like this and my idea is to somehow pass this during the test case execution. **I can't use props as this component doesn't accept any.** Is this possible?

```
const currentUser = {
    _doc: {
        _id: "60da098fe926fb878f975747",
        name: "Rukshan Jayasekara",
        role: "Attendee",
        email: "xyz@abc.com"
    }
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.